# How to change QPushButton icon size using stylesheets in Qt app

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

Is it possible to set and change the icon size on a QPushButton using stylesheets?
I need this for a qt based template that customers stylize using stylesheets.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the following code in stylesheet:

`qproperty-iconSize: 24px;`

Comment: It's better to use the normal CSS property: `icon-size: 24px;`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
qproperty-icon: url(":/img/favourit.png");
qproperty-iconSize: 14px;
```